# TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument [Python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x

In the following codes, I kept on getting the same error although I rechecked it for more than 15 minutes. For your info, I ran it on sublime text and the error:

> TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

The code is as shown below:

```
class Car():
"""A simple attempt to represent a car."""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        self.make = make
        self.model = model
        self.year = year
        self.odometer_reading = 0

    def get_descriptive_name(self):
        long_name = str(self.year) + ' ' + self.make + ' ' + self.model
        return long_name.title()

    def read_odometer(self):
        print("This car has " + str(self.odometer_reading) + " miles on it.")

    def update_odometer(self, mileage):
        if mileage >= self.odometer_reading:
            self.odometer_reading = mileage
        else:
            print("You can't roll back an odometer!")

    def increment_odometer(self, miles):
        self.odometer_reading += miles

class ElectricCar(Car):
    """Represent aspects of a car, specific to electric vehicles."""

    def __init__(self, make, model, year):
        """Initialize attributes of the parent class."""
        super().__init__(make, model, year)

my_tesla = ElectricCar('tesla', 'model s', 2016)
print(my_tesla.get_descriptive_name())
```

Comment: please fix your indentation of the Car class

Comment: Can you check that you are really using python 3 and not python 2. On many systems running "python" gets python2. `super` is different in python 2.7 and 3.x

Comment: That is in fact the error message `super()` produces when you use python2 instead of python3.

Comment: After fixing indentation I ran code in Python 3.4 with no issues.

Comment: @StevenSummers: I just realised that my subline ran python 2 by default without realising it in the first place. Now I am trying hard to change my subline so that it runs python3 by default~

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is a fairly [well documented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods?noredirect=1&lq=1) one on StackOverflow. But I'll explain how you are using `super()` incorrectly. You're using what's called [Old Style classes](https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass), while trying to use `super()`. **New style classes** inherit from [`object`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#object) and can be used in **Python 2.2** and up (*Python 3 exclusively uses New style classes*).

Your `Car` class declaration should look like this -> `class Car(object):` (`Car` *inherits from the* `object` *built-in*), with your `super` call having the class the object is in, and `self` passed in as arguments:

```
super(ElectricCar, self).__init__(make, model, year)
```

Now, if we *print* out the type of object `my_tesla` is:

```
>>> print type(my_tesla)
<class '__main__.ElectricCar'>
```

We can see it's of type `ElectricCar`.

Now why is all this important? Well there are a few key differences between the styles. In the Old style, the class and the objects it defines for instantiating are of *different* types. In Old style classes, instances are always of type `instance`, regardless of their class. With New style classes, an instance is generally going to share the same type that it's class has. Examples:

**Old Style** ->

```
>>> class MyClass:
    pass
>>> print type(MyClass)
>>> print type(MyClass())
<type 'classobj'>
<type 'instance'>
```

**New Style** ->

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
    pass
>>> print type(MyClass)
>>> print type(MyClass())
<type 'type'>
<class '__main__.MyClass'>
```

Please refer to Python's official documentation on [`super()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#super).